# Trouble with bluetooth communicating on iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, nsstream, multipeer-connectivity

I have an application that has to sand NSData quickly via bluetooth. The problem is delay between sending and receiving NSData (with length 367 and freq at least 10 pockets in a second) becomes bigger and bigger with time.

```
DELAY:
0.111
...
1.124
...
20.02
...
50.12
```

Now i trying to send data with method `sendData:toPeers:withMode:error:`.
I can't believe that Bluetooth can't send even 4KBps normally (tested on 2 iPhone 5s). How can I fix it? Will NSInputStreams(NSOutputStreams) help me?

P.S.: When I using Wi-Fi with the same code, everything is looking good even with freq 60 pockets a second.

Updated: When I tring to use stream, they always close after a few seconds.